# Ratio of difference between convex function of real variables and difference between real variables

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a convex real-valued function. Then the ratio of f(x1) - f(x2) to x1 - x2 should be non-decreasing. I think I know this, but I do not know how to show it. How does this follow from the definition of a convex function?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x<y<x'<y'$. Then $y=\frac {x'-y} {x'-x} x+\frac {y-x} {x'-x} x'$. Note that $\frac {x'-y} {x'-x}$ and $\frac {y-x} {x'-x} $ are positive numbers adding up to $1$. Applying the definition of convexity we get $f(y)\leq \frac {x'-y} {x'-x} f(x)+\frac {y-x} {x'-x} f(x')$. You can re-write this as $\frac {f(y)-f(x)} {y-x} \leq \frac {f(x')-f(y)} {x'-y}$. Next write $x'$ as $\frac {y'-x'} {y'-y} y+\frac {x'-y} {y'-y} y'$. As above this gives $\frac {f(x')-f(y)} {x'-y} \leq \frac {f(y')-f(x')} {y'-x'}$. Combining the two inequalities we have proved we get $\frac {f(y)-f(x)} {y-x} \leq \frac {f(y')-f(x')} {y'-x'}$.

There are other inequalities of this type. If you change only one of the two numbers $x,y$ to a larger number then also the ratio increases. Such inequalities are proved by a similar argument.